Karaf 4.2.16 not recognizing cxf namespace
Working on Karaf 4.2.16, blueprint attributes are getting identified by Karaf but having issue with CXF namespace.
CXF namespace are not recognized by karaf 4.2.16

Logs: Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintStateService            | 107 - org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate - 4.2.9 | Blueprint app state changed to Starting for bundle 455 2024-11-18T09:37:27,032 | DEBUG | Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintStateService            | 108 - org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate - 4.2.16 | Blueprint app state changed to Starting for bundle 455 2024-11-18T09:37:27,034 | INFO  | fileinstall-C:\\Software\\apache-karaf-4.2.16/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 55 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.2 | Blueprint bundle test/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT is waiting for namespace handlers \[http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf, http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint%5C%5C%5C%5C\] 2024-11-18T09:37:27,034 | DEBUG | Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintStateService            | 107 - org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate - 4.2.9 | Blueprint app state changed to GracePeriod for bundle 455 2024-11-18T09:37:27,035 | DEBUG | Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintStateService            | 108 - org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate - 4.2.16 | Blueprint app state changed to GracePeriod for bundle 455 2024-11-18T09:37:27,036 | DEBUG | Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintStateService            | 107 - org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate - 4.2.9 | Blueprint app state changed to Starting for bundle 455 2024-11-18T09:37:27,036 | DEBUG | Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1 | BlueprintStateService            | 108 - org.apache.karaf.bundle.blueprintstate - 4.2.16 | Blueprint app state changed to Starting for bundle 455 2024-11-18T09:37:27,038 | INFO  | fileinstall-C:\\Software\\apache-karaf-4.2.16/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 56 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Blueprint bundle test/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT is waiting for namespace handlers \[http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf%5C%5C%5C%5C\]

Installed the repositories for camel and cxf, installed features but issue still exists.
feature: repo-add camel 3.6.0 feature: install camel feature:install camel-stream

Appreciate on any help
